# QA C warning message in C Code

Tags: c

I wrote a following piece of code and analysed through QA C but it shows a warning 'x' has external linkage and is being defined without any previous declaration. Kindly help me to understand this.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x;
void main()
{
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for [re-opening](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37672587/revisions)? [Anything specific that the marked dupe had missed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5110055/2173917)

Comment: Is QA C set to check for MISRA-compliance, per chance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tool is correctly warning you against using bad programming practice. I suspect this is because you have the static analyser set to check for MISRA-C compliance.

First of all MISRA-C does not allow "global" variables, MISRA-C:2012 rule 8.7:

> Functions and objects should not be defined with external linkage if
>   they are referenced in only on translation unit.

Meaning this variable would either have to be `static` or `extern`.

The former makes sense, the latter is almost always very bad programming practice (with a few exceptions like some `const` variables).

Now, if you intended to have this variable `extern`, then there's another rule, which is likely the cause of the error, MISRA-C:2012 rule 8.4:

> A compatible declaration shall be visible when an object or function
>   with external linkage is defined.

Meaning that for MISRA compliance, you would need to have the extern declaration `extern int x` visible inside the same translation unit. MISRA recommends putting it in a header file.

Also please note that bad code like this is flagged obsolescent by the standard and might not work in future versions of C, see C11 6.11.2:

> 6.11.2 Linkages of identifiers
>
> Declaring an identifier with internal linkage at file scope without the static storageclass
>   specifier is an obsolescent feature.

Even if it wasn't flagged as obsolete practice by C, you should still *always* avoid global variables and `extern`, since that is the road to spaghetti programming and spaghetti tight coupling. Consider a different program design entirely.

Answer (score 6):

All it means is that `x` *could* be accessible *outside* the translation unit containing the above code. So its value *could* be changed by other translation units.

So the compiler is warning you of a potential loss of program stability.

But the **elephant in the room**. Fix that non-portable `void main()` prototype. Use `int main()`. Pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: It's not an elephant, it's a dead horse... In case the OP's code is for an embedded system, this format of main is perfectly fine and portable. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518). Also, QA C is not a compiler but a static analyser.