# How can I make my code in compliance with MISRA 2012 RULE 8.4

Tags: c, misra

I added this line in my c code

```
uint64_t *ab_cd;  //Line 1
```

It throws an error stating  "external symbol 'ab_cd' defined without a prior declaration".

RULE 8.4 says that "A compatible declaration shall be visible when an object or function with external linkage is defined"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QA C warning message in C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37673682/105104)

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
extern uint64_t *ab_cd;
```

Somewhere before your variable definition. Probably in a header, if this variable is intended to be shared between compilation units. If it’s not, maybe making this variable `static` would be a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file, upon which this variable has been declared, belongs in the directory which is used to check for MISRA compliance. If you do not do this, then the header file won't be included and when the automated program reads the variable definition it will interpret this as a variable which has not been declared. Makes more sense with functions.

Comment: Lewis, once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: Now that you have an answer post here, you can comment on it like "If you clarify what program you are using I could improve my answer with details on ....".